# Opengl texture binding and rendering performance dependent of the texture size

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures

If i have a 1024 x 1024 texture and only use a 128x128 portion of it. Is the state change of binding that texture (in openGL) slower than binding a 128 x 128 texture?

Is the rendering slower if i use the 1024 x 1024 texture rather than using the 128 x 128, even if i only read a 128 x 128 portion of the big texture?

I ask this because i have many textures in an atlas, but normally they are used alone. I don't know if is better simply loading textures alone.

Comment: Actually *binding* the texture? Probably not. Sampling the texture, on the other hand, could theoretically be slower. GPUs generally keep the entire texture image for a texture resident and this would boil down to cache performance assuming you are not running into thrashing because of limited VRAM constraints. More realistically, and easier to objectively measure, you are using textures with 64x the necessary storage in this example. That is a massive waste of memory, even if it turns out to have no performance implication.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman , why not making this an awnser instead of a comment?